# multi add item on select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I creating a input data form as image:
[image]

When I entered the national data in the inputext1,then SelectList below load data about the states so I can choose the state. It worked fine when I create each row form data input. But if I create more than one row form data input, The data states I got is states of end country I choose end.

My InputText1:

```
<span editable-text="data.country" e-name="country"
    e-typeahead-wait-ms="100"
    e-typeahead="country in countries  | filter: $viewValue | limitTo:8" e-typeahead-on-select='onSelect($item)'
    e-ng-readonly="isDisable(data)"  e-form="rowform"
    onbeforesave="validateCountry($data)" e-required class="dropdown"
    on-toggle="toggled(open)"> <a href class="dropdown-toggle">
            {{ data.country }} </a>
</span>
```

My SelectList:

```
<span editable-select="data.states" e-name="states" ng-width="30px" 
    e-form="rowform"    e-ng-readonly="isDisable(data)"
    e-ng-options="states.id as states.name for states in statesArr "
     e-required></span>{{showStatesName(data.states)}}
```

My js:

```
$scope.data = [];
$scope.countries = [];
$scope.statesArr = [];

$scope.loadData = function() {
    $http.get(loadDataURL, config).success(function(data) {
        $scope.totalItems = data.totalItems;
        $scope.data = data.pageItems;

        $http.get(getCountriesURL, config).success(function(data) {          
            $scope.countries = data;
        });
    });
};

$scope.onSelect(item) {
    $http.get(getStatesURL, config).success(function(data) {
        $scope.statesArr = data;
    });
}
```

Is there any suggestion for create more than one row form data?

Answer (score 0):

It's not specific answer for your question but if you dont find it I suggest using isteven multi-select, it is easier to customize it and pretty easy to implement. It has multi select, single select etc etc.

Check it:

Git: https://github.com/isteven/angular-multi-select

Demo: http://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/#/main

License: 
The MIT License (MIT)

Copyright (c) 2014-2015 Ignatius Steven (https://github.com/isteven)

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.